# Remove comma to the last string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$(".value").append($("#txtValue").val()).attr("class", "values");
```

Example: If the `#txtValue` value is 'Apple, Banana,' how can I remove the comma (, ) to last last value using the code I have in the above or if it detected that the value has the last string  of comma (,). I just want to have the get the value like this: 'Apple, Banana'

Comment: I guess simple googling could give you answer!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution but regexp is a good method i think.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
            //Make a .trim() before
        var stuff = "Apple, Banana,";

        var result = (stuff.substr(stuff.length-1, 1) == ",")? stuff.substr(0, stuff.length-1):stuff;
        alert(result);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```
var val = $("#txtValue").val(),
    txt = val.slice(-1) === ',' ? val.slice(0, - 1) : val;

$(".value").append(txt).attr("class", "values");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Uq4zZ/

Comment: It output nothing, but when I alert the variable it is ok.

Comment: @user00602 Are you sure that you want to `append`, and not simply set the value? I.e. `$(".value").val(txt)`

Comment: I want to append the value I got to a particular class like this one: $(".SroleValue").append(str).attr("class", "roleValues");

Answer (score 1):

Or using regex :

```
var str = 'Apple, Banana,'.replace(/,$/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

var string =  "Apple,Banana,";
var lastIndex = string.lastIndexOf(",");
if((string.length - 1) == lastIndex){
    console.log(string.substring(0,lastIndex));
}